# Where to start looking to figure out why a document is not showing up in search?

Tags: search

I have a document that I can't get to show up in search.  When I say search I mean the default search box at the top of the page as well as custom FullTextSqlQuerys.  I've been [monitoring the ULS logs](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/any-idea-why-i-would-get-this-error-when-executing-a-fulltextsqlquery) but haven't really seen anything that would explain why I'm not seeing my document.

I'm not sure if this matters but the page uses a custom page layout with a code behind.  I have quite a bit of logging in there and the code behind runs fine.

Can anyone suggest where to start to figure out why my document isn't showing up?

**UPDATE:**

So far I have tried the following

- Using [SearchCoder](http://mosssearchcoder.codeplex.com/) ran a query that just selected everything
- Using [SearchCoder](http://mosssearchcoder.codeplex.com/) ran a query where `Path = 'PageName.aspx'`
- Using the search box at the top of SharePoint pages I searched for a snippit of the page text
- Using a FullTextSqlQuery ran a query that should have returned this document

None of these have returned the page.

Comment: What have you tried? As in, what keywords are you trying and where in the page is the content you expect to be indexed for those keywords?

Comment: Take a look at my update to see what I have tried so far.  The text snippit I searched for was in the `Page Content` of my page.

Comment: Do you have scope rules that could be excluding that page?

Comment: Do you have permissions to see the document in SharePoint with the same account you are searching with?  Worth checking the document isnt being security trimmed from the results.

Comment: @JamesLove - No there shouldn't be anything getting excluded by the default scope.  When I run the searches from SearchCoder or my own FullTextSqlQuerys I do not specify a scope

Comment: @ChrisJohnson - Yes I can view the document by typing in the URL manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search crawl runs using a specific domain account and if your custom code is expecting something specific (i.e. a user profile) then it may be erroring out which would explain why the crawl is not picking up the page.  I would check your crawl logs and look for any errors.

Additionally, check both the list that contains the document and the site and verify that they are both set to be included in the crawl.  I've seen cases where they are hidden from the crawl intentionally and then that gets forgotten about.

Comment: How would I check to see if a list is excluded from the crawl?

Comment: Go to your list, then go to List Settings -> Advanced -> Search.  To check it at the site level, go to Site Settings -> Search Visibility

Comment: Yeah looks like this was the cause.  We were running a powershell script that was setting `$spList.NoCrawl = $true`